# Elasticsearch term query with spaces not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to execute the following query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "Thing.Name": {
              "value": "(item) test",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  }
}
```

This is not yielding results and I have no idea why. I have parens and a space. What are my options here?

Comment: term query isn't analyzed and hence it will match the documents which contains exact same tokens.. In your case can you provide the tokens of your `Thing.Name` field ?

Answer (score 2):

You want to match exact value for which you are using term query. As Amit mentioned in the comment that term query doesn't use analyzer and hence it will match the documents which contains exact same tokens you need to modify the mapping for Thing.Name  as below:

```
{
  "Thing": {
    "properties": {
      "Name": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If the mapping is auto generated by elastic then it will have similar properties for name field as above. If it is already this then you need not make any modifications in the mapping. Update you query to use `Thing.Name.keyword` instead of `Thing.Name` since a field of type `keyword` doesn't analyze the value and generate a single token, which is the input value itself.

So the query will be :

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "Thing.Name.keyword": {
              "value": "(item) test",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  }
}
```